# Customizing Google Visualization PieChart look and feel with circular border and slice margins

Tags: google-api, google-visualization

I am using Google's Visualization API to create embedded Pie Charts in my web application.

http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart.html

The API works great, I am just having a problem with the look and feel customization.

http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_charts.html

I can't figure out if there is a way to:

1. Make the border around a Pie Chart Circular and not rectangular
2. Editing the width and color of the pie slice margins/seperators?

Comment: did you ever find an answer for this? I'm experiencing the same issue...

Comment: +1 looking everywhere for that customizing charts link.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would do:

Using [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) with Firefox select the chart and look at the CSS. Find the name of the border by selecting it with Firebug.

Next:

1.) Create a CSS to remove the border and embed the chart into a DIV with the border you want. Depending on browser compatibility you may want to use images instead of CSS for the rounded border.

OR

2.) Use CSS to change the border into what you want.

Comment: Google visualization loads the chart content into and IFrame, so I don't think I can override the styles from the css loaded in my page. By using chrome developer tools, I did notice that the color is set by the stroke and stroke-width values of a path element. These values are not changed by backgroundColor:{fill,stroke,strokeWidth} however.